# Combining new apostrophe-cms project with existing Gulp.js project

Tags: sass, gulp, apostrophe-cms

I recently found out about Apostrophe CMS when I was searching for a Wordpress/TYPO 3 alternative and I must say, I'm really impressed! Needless to say, I'm also a bit overwhelmed with all the stuff that is coming together in this huge framework.

So my question is: how do I combine my existing gulp project with hot-reload, sass-stylesheets etc. with Apostrophe in the most efficient way?

I figured Apostrophe would work pretty well with the technology I'm already using, but there also seems to be no documentation on how to do something like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the custom front end source files wherever (`src` or `frontend` in the root is popular). You'll push it with [`self.pushAsset`](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-module/#pushasset-type-name-options) in the module where you've output the built assets. There's some more about this in [the docs for the `apostrophe-assets` module](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-assets/). (this could certainly be wrapped up better for new devs)

As it says there, front end assets not specific to a particular module (e.g., player JS for your custom carousel widget) should still go in a module you own. An `assets` module is a good choice (you have to declare it in `app.js` like the others). So you might have something like:

```
// in lib/modules/assets/index.js
module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'styles', { when: 'always' });
  }
}
```

`styles` there as the `name` argument indicates that the file name is `styles.css` (your output file from the build). Since the type is `stylesheet`, this file is located in the assets module public CSS directory, `lib/modules/assets/public/css/styles.css`. That's covered in the `pushAsset` docs linked above.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer! I'll have a look at it in a few days and will report back.

Comment: Hi there, I've tried a lot but in the end I have come to the conclusion to try and solve my problem with the apostrophe headless module (which was really hard to find as well).

See, I'm not just trying to push a few stylesheets to apostrophe. So I guess the REST based approach is going to be the best.